# Selecting record by a range of months

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have a table with a `start_date` and `end_date` for each row. `end_date` can by of a different year than the start date.

I need to select all records that overlap an input months range.

For example:

```
n  start_date  end_date  
1  2010-12-03  2010-03-29  // months are 12,1,2,3  
2  2012-03-11  2010-06-24  // months are 3,4,5,6  
3  2010-06-17  2010-10-04  // months are 6,7,8,9,10  
4  2010-07-03  2010-09-21  // months are 7,8,9  
5  2010-04-21  2011-05-13  // months are 1..12
```

The input range is 3,4,5,6. The output rows should be: 1,2,3,5.
Only row 4 doesn't have an overlap in any of the months.

How do I perform this in SQlite/MySQL?

I'm using Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Could the input range be 11,12,1,2 ?

Comment: Yes. It means the the row started at Nov and ended up in Feb.

Answer (score 1):

"Input Range" sounds like a connected range. So without 12-month-range the typical solution would be `where month(start_date) <= $end_month and month(end_date) >= $start_month`.

But that way we need the whole range with modulo. I would roll out the relations to months 1..24.

That means the range is:

```
month(start_date) ... month(end_date) + 12*(year(end_date) - year(start_date))
```

Now the given range `$from, $to` must be rolled out:

```
if($to < $from){ 
    $to += 12;
}
```

And the relation rolls out to

```
month(start_date) <= $to 
and (month(end_date) + 12*(year(end_date) - year(start_date))) >= $from
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It doesn't solve the case where the search range is Jan-March (1..3) and there's a row with start_date: Dec-2010, end_date: Dec-2011. This roll out would give 12..24 which doesn't overlap 1..3.

Comment: Oh, true. But I'm sure there is a good modulo- solution whithout listing the numbers 1..12 inside the query... I just try to avoid an "or" clause because it kills index-usage...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it in a single piece of SQL:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT n
FROM SomeTable,
(SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11) a
WHERE DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(SomeTable.start_date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(SomeTable.start_date)-1 DAY), INTERVAL a.i MONTH) <= SomeTable.end_date
AND MONTH(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(SomeTable.start_date, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(SomeTable.start_date)-1 DAY), INTERVAL a.i MONTH)) IN (3, 4, 5, 6)
```

This is adding up to 11 months to each start date as long as the resulting date is less than or equal to the end date for that row. This potentially gives you 12 resulting rows per initial row, one for each month in that range, and this is checked with an IN clause against the months you wanted to check.

The odd playing around with DATE_SUB within the brackets is to use the 1st day of the month. Otherwise adding a month to 2013:02:28 would give a date that was greater than 2013:03:01, hence you would only get Feb and not March without this playing around.

Comment: In rails as in with activerecord??

Comment: No. I know active records can't do this. I managed to run:SELECT DISTINCT * FROM  Table, (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11) a; in sqlite console but I don't know how to insert this expression to active records find/where. It complains about the 'a'

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQLite? Not used Sqlite much but it might insist on using AS for giving an alias to a subselect. It works for me in MySQL (although just realised that your start_date values can be after the end_date values, and it won't cope with that).

Answer (score 0):

`SomeClass.where("start_date >= ? end_date <= ?", start_date.beginning_of_month, end_date.end_of_month)`